# sum of two numbers using raw_input in python

Tags: python

I want to perform this:

Read two integers from STDIN and print three lines where:

The first line contains the sum of the two numbers.
The second line contains the difference of the two numbers (first - second).
The third line contains the product of the two numbers.

Can someone help me on this?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

Start slow and break it down

```
# Get your data from the user, use input
num_one = input("Please enter the first number: ")
num_two = input("Please enter the second number: ")

# Create the sum, diff, and product, casting as integer
sum = int(num_one) + int(num_two)
diff = int(num_one) - int(num_two)
product = int(num_one) * int(num_two)

# Print each output casting as a string since we can't concatenate a string to an integer
print("The sum is: "+str(sum))
print("The difference is: "+str(diff))
print("The product is: "+str(product))
```

Now you should also do some error checking here incase the user doesn't enter anything:

```
 # Get your data from the user, use input
num_one = input("Please enter the first number: ")
num_two = input("Please enter the second number: ")

if(num_one == "" or num_two == ""):
    print("You did not enter enter two numbers. Exiting...")
    exit
else:
    # Create the sum, diff, and product, casting as integer
    sum = int(num_one) + int(num_two)
    diff = int(num_one) - int(num_two)
    product = int(num_one) * int(num_two)

    # Print each output casting as a string since we can't concatenate a 
    string to an integer
    print("The sum is: "+str(sum))
    print("The difference is: "+str(diff))
    print("The product is: "+str(product))
```

Comment: Start slow, break it down, but without spoon feeding them the solution. At least edit out the important parts and ask them to fill it in, or else they don't learn.

Answer (score 0):

## Python 2.7

[raw_input](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input) to read the input, [int](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#int) to convert string to integer, `print` to print the output

```
a = int(raw_input("numebr 1: "))
b = int(raw_input("numebr 2: "))
print a + b
print a - b
print a * b
```

## Python 3.7

[input](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input) to read the input, [int](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int) to convert string to integer, print to [print](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print) the output

```
a = int(input("numebr 1: "))
b = int(input("numebr 2: "))
print (a + b)
print (a - b)
print (a * b)
```

Answer (score -1):

```py
a = int(input())
b = int(input())
from operator import add, sub, mul
operators = [add, sub, mul]
for operator in operators:
    print(operator(a, b))
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: @MotKohn you missed an opportunity to suggest an edit and earn some points, as well as put your name next to mine. Also, if you'd give my code a vote up, it would rise higher than others and your name would appear there as well for more visibility. Just sayin.

Comment: You're not using `raw_input` as the question requires.